# How to build nix hello world

Tags: nix

I'm trying to get started with a simple [Hello World derivation](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ch-simple-expression) using the Nix manual.
But it's not clear to me how to go about building it.

- Is there somewhere I can download the source files from so I don't
  have to copy them line-by-line?
- Is there a way I can `nix-build` it
  *without* having to modify anything global (eg `pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix`)?
- Where is `pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix`?

Answer (score 4):

One option is to clone the [nixpkgs repository](https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs) and then build the hello package recipe provided in that repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs
cd nixpkgs
nix-build -A hello
```

Doing it this way, you don't have to modify `all-packages.nix`, because it already has an entry for `hello`.  If you do want to modify `all-packages.nix`, you can find it in the nixpkgs repository that you cloned.  Just take the path of the repository you cloned, (e.g. `~/nixpkgs`) and add `pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix` to get the path to `all-packages.nix`.  You can see a copy of that file here:

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix

When you start building your own software that is not part of nixpkgs, you might chose to write your own `default.nix` file in your own repository and put a line like this in there to import nixpkgs, using the `NIX_PATH` environment variable:

```
let
  nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> { };
...
```

Comment: Note that if you run `nix-build -A hello` it will use `$NIX_PATH` to find the `hello` package, even if you `cd nixpkgs`. To make `nix-build` use your nixpkgs clone, after `cd nixpkgs` run `nix-build -I $PWD -A hello`.

Comment: That doesn't match my experience.  `nix-build` looks for default.nix in the current directory.

Comment: Ah, you're right. nixpkgs/default.nix indirectly defines packages and their dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Note that I am running `NixOs`, not sure if my answer will valid for other (non-Linux) system.

> Is there somewhere I can download the source files from so I don't have to copy them line-by-line?

You could browse [nixpkgs](https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs), All source files are there.

> Is there a way I can `nix-build` it without having to modify anything global (eg pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix)?

David Grayson give excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48471279/1664572) already.

I would love to add some information.

`nix-build` will looking for `default.nix` on the current directory and the build result will symlink named `result` on current working directory.

Another way to test if nix expression could build is `nix-shell` which also looking for `default.nix` or `shell.nix` on current directory. If the build success you will get shell prompt with your packages avaliable.

Both `nix-build` and `nix-shell` have `-I` argument that you can point to any `nix` repository including remote one.

For example, if I use `nix-shell -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/master.tar.gz -p hello`, `nix` will download `binary cache` if exists or build `hello` using current `master` branch expression and give me a shell which `hello` is avaliable.

```
$ nix-shell -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/master.tar.gz -p hello
downloading ‘https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/master.tar.gz’... [12850/0 KiB, 1404.5 KiB/s]
unpacking ‘https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/master.tar.gz’...
these paths will be fetched (0.04 MiB download, 0.19 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/s3vlmp0k8b07h0r81bn7lh24q2mqcai8-hello-2.10
fetching path ‘/nix/store/s3vlmp0k8b07h0r81bn7lh24q2mqcai8-hello-2.10’...

*** Downloading ‘https://cache.nixos.org/nar/1ax9cr6qqqqrb4pdm1mpqn7whm6alwp56dvsh5hpgs5g8rrpnjxd.nar.xz’ (signed by ‘cache.nixos.org-1’) to ‘/nix/store/s3vlmp0k8b07h0r81bn7lh24q2mqcai8-hello-2.10’...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 40364  100 40364    0     0  40364      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 37099


[nix-shell:~]$ which hello
/nix/store/s3vlmp0k8b07h0r81bn7lh24q2mqcai8-hello-2.10/bin/hello
```

> Where is pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix?

There is `NIX_PATH` enviroment variable. The `nixpkgs` portion will point you to your current repository

```
$ echo $NIX_PATH 
nixpkgs=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixpkgs:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels
```

My `all-packages.nix` is located at `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix`